# How to disable 4 finger gestures on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm testing an iPad on iOS 4.3, which by default uses 4 finger (up/down) gestures to switch out of apps.  This interferes with an on-screen piano keyboard I'm using, however, and want to remove this gesture within the frame of the keyboard. The keyboard does not use the gesture, but it regularly disrupts input (for example, when there is multi-touch input).

Comment: I would like to know as well. In the end, did you manage to do it ? thx Louis

Answer (score 11):

One way to detect this is you will get **4 touchesCancelled** at once in a single `(NSSet *)touches` event if the person accidentally did the 4 finger swipe, and **5 touchesCancelled**  if the person did the 5 finger grab.

At that point you can display a dialog box in your app, telling the user how to turn off the multitasking gestures, once he switches back to the app.

Comment: While hackish, this is as good a solution as it gets at this time.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you go to settings> general> Multitasking gestures and turn them off.

Comment: Is it possible to set this programmatically, application-wide?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean, sorry

Comment: He means that instead of having to disable multitasking gestures via settings, is it possible for the app to do it? Can we program the app to disable it?

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I don't think you can as Apple has not shipped the gestures in iOS therefore it's a developer only setting and cannot be edited as it won't be usable to consumers.

Comment: Yeah.. the geniuses (uhem..uhem) at Apple didn't realize that developers might want their own 4 finger swipe behavior OR that little children often can only swipe with 4 fingers.

Comment: Anyone can change that setting BUT developers. At least, afaik. The old rule - you can't change peoples' settings.

Answer (score 4):

**No Dice**

This is currently impossible to do programmatically. The most complete thread on it is here:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/28704

and the answer, if it were true, would probably be here (it's not):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html

**Other Possibilities**

The other way to go would be **at least** to inform the user that they have the setting "wrong." Can you detect it? It seems you cannot:

[iOS Multitasking gestures: Is there any way to check if the user has them turned on or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009590)