# iOS Multitasking gestures: Is there any way to check if the user has them turned on or not?

Tags: ios, multitasking-gestures

I know there's no way for my app to *control* multitasking gestures, but I'm wondering if there might be a way I can check to see if they're on or off.

Comment: I've been looking for the way but now I am exhausted. I think it is impossible now and I'm curious why there is no any option to turn on/ off programmatically. It is so fun !

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know its not possible to know from code if this feature is ON or OFF.

This can only be turned ON or OFF by the user from the "Settings".

Well if we are talking about Jailbroken iOS device, then its a different ball-game. There it might be possible to do this.