# iPad - How to detect that multitasking gestures are enabled?

Tags: ios, ipad, multitasking-gestures

I created an iPad app in which it is helpful if multitasking gestures are not enabled. I know you cannot disable them from the app itself (thank god apps can't decide that on their own). But what I want to do is display a warning on startup if multitasking gestures are enabled and advice the user to turn them off for optimal usage.

I've seen apps do this very same thing, like Apple's GarageBand. In that app multitasking gestures can disturb the working of the app when you're playing piano for instance. Garageband displays a warning exactly like the one I want to display.

The setting for multitasking gestures I'm talking about is located in Settings > General > Multitasking gestures.

Comment: Have you seen apps from other developers than Apple show a warning like this? That would indicate that it is indeed possible to detect the setting.

Comment: I did never see any other app do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me, that it's impossible..
A branch with the same topic

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10193865/1209976