# disable gesture control for iPad programmatically in xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, gesture

I've made an iPad game for toddlers to teach them how to move stuff around, like a drag-n-drop. The problem with children too young is that they put all their fingers on the screen which sometimes result in a multitasking gesture. With 4 fingers swiping, they accidentally switch to another app which is very frustrating!

Not sure if I can access this property programmatically? If not, can I do something to prevent it happening by for example using some kind of special flow of elements. Don't know, but imagining something that maybe needs an "ok"-button or similar to get out from the view/window?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable 4 finger gestures on iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526960/how-to-disable-4-finger-gestures-on-ipad)

Comment: Any kind of workaround? It's hard to tell a 2 year old not to swipe with a random number of fingers... :)

Comment: No, but the parent can be told about the feature and to consider disabling it in Settings app. I'm not aware of another workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Multi touch is iOS key feature and its not possible to stop programatically any how but if your game can handle multi touch gesture and respond then it might work for you in a way!

Answer (score 0):

Multi touch feature is an in built feature provided by apple for its devices and they can not be disabled.