# Can I disable the home screen pinch in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

For various reasons, I don't want to enter kiosk mode, and I don't want to disable the home button completely. I want users to be able to return to the home screen by pressing the home button, but that should be the only way to leave the app. I'm aware that this is bad UI design etc, I'm not planning on uploading this to App Store. Is there a way to disable the home screen pinch? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526960/how-to-disable-4-finger-gestures-on-ipad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean on the iPad? The pinch gestures are all under the setting...

```
Settings - General - Multitasking Gestures.
```

Just turn that off and it removes the home screen pinch.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you're doing this for an in-house app, like an unskippable welcome screen. Apple actually introduced a feature for this, called "**guided access**".

> Settings `>` General `>` Accessability `>` Guided Access

Enable and set a passcode, now you can click 3 times the home button and restrict features of an app. **The app cannot be abandoned in guided access**.

Unlike just disabling the multitasking gesture, this allows to password-lock an app in place, if this is what suits you.